# What are the best ways to run a Ruby script as a subprocess/another thread from Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I have a Sinatra app I plan on hosting on Heroku.

This application, in part, scrapes **a lot** of information from other pages around the net and stores the information to a database. These scrapping operations are a slow process, so I need them to run in another thread/process separate from my Sinatra app.

My plan is just to have a button for each process that I can click and the scrapping will take place in the background.

I'm unsure what's the best way to do this, complicated by what Heroku will allow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a gem called [hirefire](https://github.com/meskyanichi/hirefire) specifically for that:

> HireFire automatically "hires" and "fires" (aka "scales") Delayed Job
>   and Resque workers on Heroku. When there are no queue jobs, HireFire
>   will fire (shut down) all workers. If there are queued jobs, then
>   it'll hire (spin up) workers. The amount of workers that get hired
>   depends on the amount of queued jobs (the ratio can be configured by
>   you). HireFire is great for both high, mid and low traffic
>   applications. It can save you a lot of money by only hiring workers
>   when there are pending jobs, and then firing them again once all the
>   jobs have been processed. It's also capable to dramatically reducing
>   processing time by automatically hiring more workers when the queue
>   size increases.