# Background scraping on Sinatra

Tags: ruby, heroku, web-scraping, sinatra

I'm new to Ruby/Sinatra app development.

I'm building a simple Sinatra app that allows its users to select the kind of topic of data to be scraped, and then scrapes the data from webpages (takes around a minute, lots of data), retrieves/displays the results. The information doesn't need to be stored anywhere.

I was planning to host the app on a free dyno on Heroku, but discovered that it restricts HTTP request/response to 30 second limits, and was suggested to use background workers/queues.

As someone completely new to Ruby/Sinatra, I'm having trouble getting started on how I would go about passing off the scraping operation to a background worker, and getting a response back when it's done. I followed a basic flow in the application:

```
get "/scraper" do

(scraping code)

erb :results

end
```

The question is somewhat similar to this: [What are the best ways to run a Ruby script as a subprocess/another thread from Sinatra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393669/what-are-the-best-ways-to-run-a-ruby-script-as-a-subprocess-another-thread-from)
but doesn't explain much to a beginner. Would be really helpful if I can get some direction on how to proceed.

Comment: For just starting out I'd recommend getting a working version locally then worrying about deploying to Heroku. Anyway, your question is kind of a hard one to answer succinctly as there are a lot of different ways to do background jobs. Gems like `background_job`, `resque`, or `sidekiq`. I just recently decided to try this and I ended up making my own little system. See the core of the backround job code [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/122159/a-two-method-program-for-running-background-jobs) or a rails app (deployed to heroku) [here](https://github.com/maxpleaner/tickers)